# Vue3/ts/setup: Import Emits/Props type to use with defineEmits<> and defineProps<>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Any idea how I can import `Emits` and `Props` interfaces and use them with `defineEmits<ImportedEmits>()` and `defineProps<ImportedProps>()`?

([Full example on sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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))

Example:

I have a `NumberFilter.ts` which provides general Emit- and Props definitions:

```js
// NumberFilter.ts
export type NumberValue = number | null

export interface NumberEmits {
  (e: 'update:value', v: NumberValue): void
  (e: 'min:value', v: NonNullable<NumberValue>): void
  (e: 'max:value', v: NonNullable<NumberValue>): void
  (e: 'increase:value', v: NonNullable<NumberValue>): void
  (e: 'decrease:value', v: NonNullable<NumberValue>): void
}

export interface NumberProps {
  value?: NumberValue
  minValue?: NonNullable<NumberValue>
  maxValue?: NonNullable<NumberValue>
  stepValue?: NonNullable<NumberValue>
}
```

Now I want to use those definitions in an actual component (e.g. `RadiusFilter`):

```
// RadiusFilter.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { NumberEmits, NumberProps } from './NumberFilter.ts'

const emit = defineEmits<NumberEmits>()
const props = withDefaults(defineEmits<NumberProps>(), {
  value: null,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 50,
  stepValue: 5,
})
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get the following errors:

```
Error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineEmits() must be a function type, a literal type with call signatures, or a reference to the above types.

Error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.
```

[Demonstration on sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm new to typescript.
Maybe I'm really just missing something really, really stupid...

---

**EDIT:**

While searching for a solution, I found [the following part from the vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features), which states that imported types are currently not supported in this specific situation, but "it is possible to support them in the future":

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following to ensure correct static analysis:
>
> - A type literal
> - A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file
>
> Currently complex types and type imports from other files are not supported. It is possible to support type imports in the future.

I still want to keep this question open as somebody might have found a usable workaround or maybe even a completely different solution for similar usecases.

Comment: If using Vite, there's a plugin that's supposed to workaround the issue by inlining the types automatically: https://github.com/wheatjs/vite-plugin-vue-type-imports. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to even run.

Comment: @tony19 thanks alot! I will at least take a decent look at this tomorrow. When did you try it out? b/c it was last updated 5 days ago. Maybe it works NOW! (Let me have hope, pls :p)

Comment: I tried it right before posting my comment.

Comment: @tony19 yea, same here, I couldn't get it to work. Even tried some forks.

Comment: I've been able to import and use props as you've shown above without error (using Vue3, script setup, webpack) however I do get an error whenever I try to import and use a child type within the interface file and then use it for props.

Here's 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936033/use-imported-type-as-child-within-interface-then-use-interface-as-props-vue3-s

Comment: @TimTitus Afaik, you can use simple types but no complex/composite types like `interface ArrayOf<T> { first: T; last: T; data: T[] }`, not being able to use those is my actual problem, and it is documented in the vue docs, [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features). Maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nebulosar's answer works fine, but adds another dependency.

**Updating to Vue 3.3+** works as well. If you *can* update, you should naturally consider it anyways.

I've tested the provided example on sfc.vuejs.org again with Vue 3.3.1 and it now works splendidly using the imported `NumberEmits` and `NumberProps` types, exactly the way I had originally intended:
[Full example on sfc.vuejs.org](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

Though, it's still not possible to directly pass ***complex*** imported types (which require type analysis) to `defineProps` or `defineEmits`.

See this [quote from the lastest (Vue 3.3+ docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props) for more detailed information:

> In version 3.2 and below, the generic type parameter for defineProps() were limited to a type literal or a reference to a local interface.
>
> This limitation has been resolved in 3.3. The latest version of Vue supports referencing imported and a limited set of complex types in the type parameter position. However, because the type to runtime conversion is still AST-based, some complex types that require actual type analysis, e.g. conditional types, are not supported. You can use conditional types for the type of a single prop, but not the entire props object.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `vue-macros` (https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/guide/getting-started.html)

Then, what you want is the `betterDefine` macro
You can use it for a better way of defining things, like type imports!

See link: https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/better-define.html
You should look into the exceptions althrough

You can find how to do this in the guide for Vue and Nuxt
Also it is worth looking into the unplugged-vue-marco for bundler integration: https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/guide/bundler-integration.html