# Use imported type as child within interface, then use interface as props (Vue3 script setup)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

This seems like a basic question, but I'm not having luck finding someone posting about it.

Using Vue3 with `script setup`

##### Goal:

TLDR: I'm trying to use a child type definition to type one key of an interface object and then use it as props within a component, but am getting a TS error (in the first image)

Import a type file (`Platform.ts`) within an interface file (`CardProps.ts`, then import and use the interface as props for a card component (`PromptCard.vue`). No error is shown if I remove the child type `Platform` with unions from the CardProps interface.

##### TS Error:

Although it renders as expected, in VScode I get the error:
[image]

I recently watched a VueSchool tutorial where it mentioned you can't use an imported interface for props (meaning it must remain in the same file). It seems to work fine, however. Is this kind of error the reason he might have said that?

#### Platform type

[image]

#### Child type inside of CardProps interface

[image]

#### Passing props to Card from Market page

[image]

#### Card Component (PrompCard.vue)

[image]

Comment: I should mention that I also don't see any intellisense for the Platform types when I am setting props (I expect that it should show my Union options, but it just says string.

Comment: When you define the cards, try adding `platform: 'Twitter' as const`

Comment: @Duannx Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't realize that I could just import Platform and type '' as Platform, which would then give me intellisense for the possible Union types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply importing the Platform type and referencing it
`platform: '' as Platform` enabled both intellisense, and removed the error. Thanks to @Duannx for giving me a hint to fix this.

[image]

CODE:

```
<template>
  <div class="market-wrapper">
    <h4>MARKETPLACE</h4>

    <div class="card-grid">
      <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
        <PromptCard :content="card" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import PromptCard from '@/components/PromptCard.vue'
import type Platform from '@/types/Platform'
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const cards = reactive([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Card Title',
    description: 'Description',
    image: '123',
    platform: 'Facebook' as Platform
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Card Title2',
    description: 'Description2',
    image: '123',
    platform: 'Twitter' as Platform
  }
])
</script>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Minor thing, could you please replace the image with the code snippet? It is better for fellow devs because we all like copy and paste :)